# CiviCRM: For some members status override comes and for some its just Status Override [ ]

Tags: php, wordpress, civicrm

From last few hours I'm stuck into a problem, my client want status override feature for every membership, but facing issues on some memberships while editing. I've also checked that myself, in some memberships it's there and in some it's not there. When I went into page source I can see memberStatus is there with correct select html. But checkbox for Status override isn't coming can someone tell me how to fix it. I'm a developer and if you guide me a little I should be able to do that. I went into code files but I don't want to do something which may create further issues.

I've attached screenshots as well, one noticeable information that I just noticed is that the problem lies usually with those membership edits which have auto-renewals checked, which is something strange to me.

Another very important problem for those membership edits which with null/[ ] override status: I got this error "There is no valid Membership Status available for selected membership dates."

I'll be really thankful if someone can guide.

Version of my CiviCRM is 4.2.12 and is installed on Wordpress.

[image: Screenshot with blank override option]

[image: Screenshot with override option]

Comment: Imran - we are trying to launch a stack exchange for civicrm - maybe you want to commit to the proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm

Answer (score 17):

CiviCRM doesn't allow admin to override status since the auto-renewal process is sequential based on earlier membership state. Any Changes in the normal workflow will no longer keep the membership in renewal state, eventually may lead to corrupt membership data.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is your auto-renew doing it. If you're overriding the status, why should it auto-renew?  Try unchecking the autorenew box.

Comment: I've tried unchecking, but it doesn't work. I've fixed the issue myself. And soon will post the solution in my blog with a link here.